# Why am I getting this 500-Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I am getting an POST 500 (Internal Server Error) on my website.

When testing on my local host i get no errors, only after publishing and running the site live do I get errors when trying to add product into cart.

In shop php file I have written ajax code for adding item into cart and passing data through ajax into action file for SQL query and this is working fine in localhost server but I'm getting error in live website. Please show me way how can I overcome this problem.

This is my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addItemBtn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form =$(this).closest(".form-submit");
            var pid=$form.find(".pid").val();
            var pname=$form.find(".pname").val();
            var pprice=$form.find(".pprice").val();
            var pimage=$form.find(".pimage").val();
            var pcode=$form.find(".pcode").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'action.php',
                method: 'get',
                data: {pid:pid,pname:pname,pprice:pprice,pimage:pimage,pcode:pcode},
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $("#message").html(response);
                    load_cart_item_number();

                }
            });
        });
        load_cart_item_number();
        function load_cart_item_number()
        { $.ajax({
            url: 'action.php',
            method: 'get', 
            data: {cartItem:"cart_item"},
            success:function(response){
                $("#cart-item").html(response);
            }

        });

        }

     });
 </script>
```

here is my second file action.php

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $pid=$_GET['pid'];
    $pname=$_GET['pname'];
    $pprice=$_GET['pprice'];
    $pimage=$_GET['pimage'];
    $pcode=$_GET['pcode'];
    $userid= $_SESSION["id"];
    $pqty=1;
     $sql = "SELECT product_id FROM cart WHERE user_id=$userid and product_id = ?";
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $pcode);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $res=$stmt->get_result();
     $row=$res->fetch_assoc();
    
     $code=$row['product_id'];
     if(!$code)
     {
        $query="INSERT INTO `cart`(`user_id`,`product_name`, `product_price`, `product_image`, `qty`, `total_price`, `product_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
         $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isisiii",$userid,$pname, $pprice,$pimage,$pqty,$pprice,$pcode);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
          echo "Added to Buy Card";

     }
     else{
        echo "Already Added In Buy Card";

     }
    }
```

Comment: Use these three lines in your PHP file on the top. ``ini_set('display_errors', '1');``
``ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');``
``error_reporting(E_ALL);``     You will get the error

Comment: Don't enable "display errors" on public servers since it can cause leaks of sensitive info. Check the webservers error log to find the actual error message instead.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your server there might be some issues. Find and try to solve that. Your browser error log is disabled. To enable and show error in browser you should use below code
//travel insurance calculator customization

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'display_startup_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

If you don't enable error to show in browser. then see your error log file in your base directory inside server. file name should be **error.log** or something else

Comment: Displaying errors should only be done on local and controlled environments. Displaying errors on a public server can cause unintentional leaks of sensitive information.

Comment: I know that. He is testing the site for 100% deployment it should see error. But he will must off error displaying in browser after everything is done. Please see the question carefully

Comment: Yes, they need to debug their live server, not their local server (where everything works), which is why I said that they should check the error log instead of sharing the error message (which can contain sensitive information) with the rest of the internet by enabling "display errors".